# Is it possible to win a tender?

Tags: word-usage, legalese

A headline in *The Moscow Times*:

> [Billionaire Rotenberg Wins Tender for Moscow to St. Petersburg
> Highway](http://www.themoscowtimes.com/business/article/billionaire-rotenberg-wins-tender-for-moscow-to-st-petersburg-highway/489672.html)

But *tender*, per dictionaries, means "a (bidder's) offer to do something".

So I'm curious, is the quoted usage of *tender* appropriate? Is it passable? If not, how does one go expressing the meaning while retaining some mention of a tender-based selection process? "Wins contract"?

And how does one go about saying in a headline that the Government has announced an international .. tender-process-driven contest (that's a mouthful) to build a plant?

In Russian, the word *tender* (тендер, a borrowing from English) is never used to denote an offer on part of a bidder to provide goods or services. It always refers to the process of selection among bidders, to the contest. So a translator has to struggle with sentences in the original language that are peppered with *tenders* thusly employed: "the company has won a tender to build a plant"; "an international tender has been announced" etc.

However, in an Australian source I've met this sentence in which the use of *tender* is also seemingly unrelated to the bidder's *tender*:

> City of Stonnington , Victoria, **has issued a tender** for drain
> construction in Glen Iris, Melbourne

Is that a shortening of "[request for tenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_tender)"?

Another Australian source, a couple of unorthodox usages of *tender*:

> [How to win contracts and tenders](http://www.manmonthly.com.au/features/how-to-win-contracts-and-tenders)
>
> The prospect of **competing for public tenders** can be daunting for
> up-and-coming SMEs. ...

How could one "compete for public tenders" if a tender is an offer on part of a candidate company to do work, provide services?

To look from another angle, there are many instances of "company wins bid to.." in headlinese. A *bid* is analogous to *tender*, so why not "company wins tender to.." ?

Comment: From Google, tender as a noun can have the meaning: an offer to carry out work, supply goods, or buy land, shares, or another asset at a stated fixed price.

Comment: I searched COCA, and found that "win the contract" is the typical usage. However, there still are a few occurrences of "win a tender", e.g. 1) *A large construction magnate, Korkmaz Yigit, who won the state tender in the nationalization of the state-owned Turkish Trade Bank, bought his way into two national newspapers and two television stations.* and 2) *Potanin's bank is a financial and industrial heavyweight, and Gusinsky feared that it could win the tender with a mountain of federal cash Potanin accumulated as one of the " authorized " banks handling government money.*

Comment: Thanks, @DamkerngT. !  Note that "win a tender" instances seem to come from non-native sources. I just wonder if "company wins tender to.." is OK from a native speaker's standpoint, is it read smoothly or gnarly by him/her. After all, there are many instances of "company wins bid to.." in headlinese.

Comment: I searched for *win* near *bid|contract|tender*, and found the results: 177, 365, and 11, in that order. From those 11, I looked up the name of the author and only those two were written by the authors whose names sound native. PS. I'm waiting for others to answer this question too. :)

Comment: How this works is that people don't read dictionaries and use words based on how other people use words.

Comment: @Kaz : If the sentence seems correct to the native speaker, I wonder what exactly he imagines reading it: The billionaire wins his *bid* or the billionaire wins *the contest* (the "call for bids" procedure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formal (financial) usage in these contexts is "tender offer." This basically means "bid." "Tender" is the adjective and "offer" is the noun.

But "tender offer" is often abbreviated to "tender." So the billionaire won his "tender" or bid to build the Moscow St. Petersburg Highway.

Comment: Wikipedia says that "tender offer" is a type of takeover bid. Could it also mean "a bid to provide services, supply goods"?

Comment: @CopperKettle: Yes. Basically, any type of bid.

Comment: Thanks! I've found instances of construction contractors' bids using  the `"tender offer" construction` query in Google: "The period for completion will either be stipulated within the tender documents or stated in the contractor's **tender offer**." (2013, *Construction Planning, Programming and Control*)

Comment: The *Call for bids* article at Wikipedia begins with "A call for bids, call for tenders, or invitation to tender (ITT) **(often called tender for short)** .. " So maybe the billionare won not his bid, but the process (i.e. contest). That's interesting..

Answer (score 1):

thefreedictionary.com defines "tender" (in the relevant sense) as:

n.
1.  A formal offer, as:
a.  Law An offer of money or service in payment of an obligation.
b.  A written offer to contract goods or services at a specified cost or rate; a bid.
2.  Something, especially money, offered in payment.

tr.v. ten·dered, ten·der·ing, ten·ders 
To offer formally: tender a letter of resignation.

From this definition it would not make sense to "win a tender", as there is nothing to win. I have most often heard the word used as a verb, as in "We tendered a bid on this contract."

By this definition it doesn't make sense to say someone "won a tender" because there is nothing to win. You tender an offer or you offer a tender, and the other person takes it or they don't. You can "win the bidding" or "win the contract", but I don't see how you would "win the tender".

A tender is something you enter in an auction or bidding process, not the competition itself. To spin an analogy: Suppose there was a horse race. You might enter your horse in the race. If you won, we would say you "won the race", not you "won the horse". (Unless the prize for winning was a horse, but you wouldn't normally expect that the prize for winning a race would be the horse that you entered into the race. You presumably already own that horse.)

That said, perhaps someone who is more familiar with contract negotiations or law would like to chime in. There may be a usage here that I am not familiar with, or some technical definition not reflected in the dictionary.